# React ssr speed in WebView

Tags: node.js, spring, reactjs, server-side-rendering

I created an reactive web application using `ReactJS`.
It can do `SSR`.
Every browser is OK, but it load slowly only in webview..

It occured only in the `ReactJS` applcation.

The web application developed by `spring` doesn't have this problem.
It can load the page at once.
it means, every contents appear at once(except image).

But this `ReactJS` application(using `Node`) is not.
Even thought it is text, it isn't load at once... it load like step by step.

Our application link is https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.seeon.hotplace&hl=ko
if you have time, check my application's phenomenon..
Enter the application, and click any picture.
Then you can see this phenomenon that I said.

So.. What is the thing I have to check?
I really wanna fix this phenomenon, but I don't know what I should check.